# Help needed on homogeneous functions

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives

If $f$ is homogeneous of degree $1$, is differentiable at $0$ and $f(0)=0$, how can i prove that: $f(x) = \bigtriangledown f(0)\cdot x$

Answer (score 1):

If $f$ is homogeneous of degree $1$, then $f(tx) = t f(x)$ for $t \ge 0$. Deriving this with respect to $t$ (and using the chain rule for derivatives) we get

$$\sum _i \frac {\partial f} {\partial x_i} \frac {\Bbb d (t x_i)} {\Bbb d t} = f(x)$$

and evaluating at $t=0$ gives

$$\nabla f (0) \cdot x = f(x) .$$

(This is a particular case of [Euler's theorem on positive-homogeneous functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homogeneous_function#Positive_homogeneity).)